# Problem in Installing Drake (via docker) in Windows

Tags: windows, docker, drake

my configuration : windows+ dockers

I try to run the program according to the tutorial from this website:

[http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/Spring2019/install_drake_docker.html][1]

When I come to the step running the code `"**python simulator.py**"`,
it turns out to be **'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'**.
I had installed the **Xming** according to the tutorial,but still the same error.

is that mean a problem of visualization , is there any idea how to fix this problem?

[http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/Spring2019/install_drake_docker.html][1]

Answer (score 0):

We've updated the workflow for the class to use colab instead of trying to support Docker on windows.  As a result, those instructions, I'm afraid, are a bit out of date.

I see that we still link to them from https://drake.mit.edu/docker.html.  I will open an issue to update those pointers.  Is that how you found them?

Depending on your goals, might the colab workflow actually work for you, too?
http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/drake.html

Comment: I had found the tutorial in the website:https://drake.mit.edu/index.html   from the "installation and quickstart"  i think